# Adding Angular SSR throws error An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-universal

I am trying to add Server Side Rendering to my application by following the steps outlined in the [here in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-tutorial)

The 1st step is to run

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Unfortunately this throws the below error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-dark-light@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@11.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~11.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"11.2.4" from @angular/platform-server@11.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!   peer @angular/platform-server@"^11.1.2" from @nguniversal/express-engine@11.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine
npm ERR!     @nguniversal/express-engine@"11.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\KOTIENO1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KOTIENO1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-08T13_41_15_774Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "C:\Users\KOTIENO1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-m8ttIF\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I have tried to run the command with `--force` but same error is thrown

Below is my `package.json` file

```json
{
  "name": "angular-dark-light",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the problem. The problem was not related to `@angular/universal` rather npm packages mismatch between the installed and the package version on `package.json`

To resolve I followed the below steps

1. Run `npm install --force`
2. Run `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`